# URLUtil.isValidUrl returns false for a deeplink url

Tags: android, url, android-webview, url-routing, deep-linking

I have a playstore URL (market://details?id="app_package_name") where I want my app to deeplink into Google Playstore if that is clicked. Although the problem is, in my code I do a sanity check to see if a clicked URL is valid with URLUtil.isValidURL api. To my surprise it returned false for the above deeplink marketplace URL.

So my question is, how should I detect if I am passing in valid deeplink URL since I cannot use isValidURL anymore? Of course a hacky way would be to check for '://' in the string, but that's ugly.

Answer (score 1):

IsValidURL only check for certain kinds of urls (http file content). Check the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/webkit/URLUtil.java#265).

You could instead use [Uri.parse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)) and check for "market" as scheme.